# Crash Issue in android build using unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, ironsource, gameanalytics

We are currently facing huge crash issue in android build using unity version 2022..3.18f, We are some other plugin,

1. Game Analytics
2. Iron Source
3. Google Play Service
4. Radio Pro
5. Voxel Busters for in - game review
   These are internet based plugins.
   The Error message attached given below

````
"main" tid=1 Blocked at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzq.handleMessage (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:1)at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:103)at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:241)at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7888)at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native method) at `com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:512)at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:998) "GoogleApiHandler" tid=19 Native
#00  pc 0x00000000000c3e54  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__ioctl+4)
#01  pc 0x000000000007ca0c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (ioctl+132)
#02  pc 0x0000000000059e68  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+244) #03  pc 0x000000000005ada4```

I am try to find to fix this issue, Can someone help me, Thank You
````

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [ask]

Comment: Also it would be better to add versions of the plugins and the android sdk target details

Comment: @Rajat Gupta Game Analytics -7.8.0
Iron Source -7.7.0
Google Play Service-0.11.0
Radio Pro-2023.2.1
Voxel Busters-2.7.1